# An extra interface_include_directories for schema files. Is it possible?

Tags: cmake

I have successfully used [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) to pass on usage requirements to dependent C++ libraries. It all works very well. But here is a slightly different use case.

Is there a way to have a second set of include directories in addition to the normal one (i.e. the one for C/C++ headers)?

This could be convenient if you for instance have C++ libraries that are generated out of a schema language (e.g. Protobuf, Capnproto) with a 
 [`add_custom_command()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html?highlight=add_custom_command). The schema files can reference each other by `import`, so I would like to install the schema files together with the libraries.

It would be nice to pass on information to dependent libraries about the schema files directories as well as the directories for the C++ headers.

Using `target_include_directories()` to track  directories that don't contain C/C++ headers might be a misuse of that command. But maybe there is some other way of achieving this?

**Edit 1**:

Just a clarification: My goal is to have two set of directory paths, one for the C++ include headers and another one for the schema files. (The schema files and the C++ headers might not be in the same directories). The property [`INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html?highlight=interface_include_directories) will handle the C++ headers, but how should I handle the schema files?

```
yet_to_be_written_ADD_CAPNP_TARGET(
  NAME target1 
  SCHEMA ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/a1.capnp 
)
yet_to_be_written_ADD_CAPNP_TARGET(
  NAME target2 
  SCHEMA ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/a2.capnp
  DEPENDENCIES target1
)
```

A workaround could be to let
`yet_to_be_written_ADD_CAPNP_TARGET()` create two libraries

```
add_library(${name}_cxx)
add_library(${name}_schema INTERFACE)
```

instead of one library because I would then have two `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` that could remember directory paths. The purpose of the `${name}_schema` would just be to remember the schema directory paths. They could later be retrieved by the generator expression
 `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:target2_schema,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>`

and be given to the schema compiler (`/usr/bin/capnp`) in a 
 [`add_custom_command()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html?highlight=add_custom_command)

Of course this whole exercise is rather pointless if all schema files are available in the source code tree of the software project at hand but I am thinking of a scenario when cmake targets would have been imported from different external software projects. The schema files might be installed in different directories.

Another workaround would be to specify the external schema directory paths directly (without using targets to pass this information).

Answer (score 0):

Of course. I do this myself in a project I worked on with ProtoBuf files:

```
set(Aperture_PROTO
    protoinclude/bcl.proto
    protoinclude/StratusAsset.proto)
protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS ${Aperture_PROTO})
```

List the proto files as source files, so they are handled with the target:

```
LIST(APPEND Aperture_SRCS ${Aperture_PROTO})
```

Make sure to add `HEADER_FILE_ONLY` properties to the file group:

```
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${Aperture_PROTO}
                        PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY TRUE)
```

Group them distinctly in an IDE using [`source_group`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/source_group.html) for bonus points:

```
source_group("Prototype Files" FILES ${Aperture_PROTO})
```

Comment: I wrote some more explanation in **Edit 1**. Thanks for the tips in your answer,  but I am searching for some different. I am trying to find a way to have two sets of directory paths for a single target.